# Update uploaded file from the database using php

Tags: php, mysqli

I successfully uploaded my files to my database but I am having difficulties updating them.

Here are my inputs

```
<input type="file" name="technical">
<input type="file" name="contract">
<button type="submit" name="submit" id="submit"> Save</button>
```

Here is my update query

```
if (isset($_POST['submit'])) {

$id = $_GET['id'];

$technical = rand(1000000, 10000000) . "-" . $_FILES["technical"]["name"];
$temp_name = $_FILES["technical"]["tmp_name"];
$uploads_dir = 'uploads/';
move_uploaded_file($temp_name, $uploads_dir . '/' . $technical);

$contract = rand(1000000, 10000000) . "-" . $_FILES["contract"]["name"];
$tmp_name = $_FILES["contract"]["tmp_name"];
$uploads_dir = 'uploads/';
move_uploaded_file($tmp_name, $uploads_dir . '/' . $contract);

$sql="UPDATE  mytbl set Technical=:technical, Contract=:contract WHERE id=:id";
$query = $dbh->prepare($sql);
$query->bindParam(':technical',$technical,PDO::PARAM_STR);
$query->bindParam(':contract',$contract,PDO::PARAM_STR);
$query->execute();
$lastInsertId = $dbh->lastInsertId();
$msg="Successfully Updated Record";
}
```

when i click the link of my updated my file it says "object not found" or Error 404

Comment: What shows 'not found'? There's no message like that in your code. Please post the complete error message.

Comment: @TangentiallyPerpendicular when i click the link of my updated file it says "object not found"

Comment: Like @TangentiallyPerpendicular mentioned, please post full error description.

Comment: if you're storing the file in a folder `uploads/myfile.pdf` then your query need to also prepend the `$uploads_dir`... not just the filename. Unless you're adding it upon rendering the view

Comment: @SergheiLeonenco Error 404

Comment: @MisterZeroCrypto You don't have access to your page? did you check your localhost errors?

Comment: @SergheiLeonenco The error 404 occurs when i click the link of my updated file, it should show the updated file

Comment: Can you post the way how you form your link?(create)

Comment: @SergheiLeonenco <a href="uploads/<?php echo $row["Technical"]; ?>" target="_blank">View File <span class="fa fa-eye"></span></a>

Comment: Have you checked that you clicked that link at root directory?